# Eagle Multilevel BOM

Tags: eaglecad, bom

I want to do some BOM management in Eagle to make life more easy.

I want to create a multilevel BOM out of Eagle.(Multiple MPN's for the same part from different suppliers) Is this possible to manage in Eagle?
Or can I only link one MPN to each component in Eagle?

Thanks

Comment: You can create as many custom attributes as you want, but only one can be named "MPN". You could add "MPN2" or "Samsung_MPN" etc... They show up as additional columns when you export the BOM. I do this a lot with part numbers for Digikey/Allied/Newark,etc.

Comment: Assuming that you've done a little research and created your Gerber and schematic files, what exactly have you done because there's some pretty handy guides with AutoDesk that help you with your objective. However, these are pretty straight forward and if something didn't work, you should let us know.

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks it is indeed a straight forward way to do it like this. I didn't thought about this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intent is for personal use, many text-based lists can be used.

But when I was Operations Mgr for an R&D company of 50 with 15 H/W designers we CREATED an INTERNAL part number system ( called the Master Registry, aka database ), where the p/n’s had commodity codes & sometimes values & tolerance codes.  Thus only the internal part number were used on BOMs as an index to the qualified parts list (QPL).

These p/n were controlled by Design Engineers and only qualified OEM p/n’s could be added.  Then I created a Foxbase relational database, for;

BOM pick lists,
where used lists,
Purchasing stock quotes to distributors,
Inventory control,
Costed BOM analysis,
Exports to spreadsheets for least cost quotes from supplier feedback

For a database with >1k part numbers and up to 6 suppliers of any part so we could get at least 3 quotes to get best 1k~10k unit pricing on multiple assy.

Essentially this was an MRP system that didn’t cost $xxk and didn’t require 6 mos training for all staff to use.

**This is essential when the cost-saving benefits of having these features are greater than the cost of implementing it.**

Here is a snapshot of 1 page of my Master Register used by Design Engineers also showing, bin location and quantity of the Iris part number. 
[image]

Comment: I would clarify this suggestion for the purpose of OP. What you are suggesting is to create an *internal part number* that is used as index into a different database (ERP/MRP). Schematics and circuit designers only know about the "platonic ideal", and alternate manufacturers as well as vendors are managed in a different database. This means that new alternate parts can be added without going back to the schematic and modifying the libraries to add an alternate MPN.

Comment: Yes. a Relational database using only a common indexed internal part number.